# Read excel files(xlsx) file one by one in R

Tags: shiny

I have a bunch of excel file in my directory. Is there a way to read all of them separately (not appending one another) in single command. FOr example.

I have 3 files in my folder 
File1.xlsx
File2.xlsx
File3.xlsx

Expected output in R (Instead of reading them separately)

```
File1 
## should have File1 contents
File2
## should have File2 contents
File3
## should have File3 contents
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `assign` should help you - it assigns a value to a name  given as a string. So the following code should do what you want (hint: use `gsub` to clean non-word characters to make a valid variable name):

```
library(readxl)
for (file in list.files(".", pattern = "xls$", full.names = TRUE)) 
    assign(gsub("\\W", "", file), read_excel(file))
```

We observe that we have two objects in our workspace:

```
> ls()
[1] "file_1xls" "file_2xls"
```

Now let's see what they are:

```
> for(x in ls()) str(get(x))
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num 1
 $ b: num 2
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ c: num 4
 $ d: num 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code

- loads the readxl library
- creates a variable of the files in the current directory with the .xlsx extension
- then reads in the files with the lapply() function into a dataframe list

`library(readxl)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)`

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.